# SVG D3 image resize issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I have an SVG image created using d3. I want to contain the svg image within the it's parent div container. However, svg is going beyond the parent div. Below is my code:

```
    <div id="test" style="{width: 500px; height:500px;}">
    <svg></svg>
    </div>
     <script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
            width = +svg.attr("width"),
            height = +svg.attr("height"),
            node,
            link;

        svg.append('defs').append('marker')
            .attrs({'id':'arrowhead',
                'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
                'refX':13,
                'refY':0,
                'orient':'auto',
                'markerWidth':13,
                'markerHeight':13,
                'xoverflow':'visible'})

            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
            .attr('fill', '#999')
            .style('stroke','none');

</script>
```

My d3 graph is going beyond parent "test" div. How can I limit SVG graph within parent container.

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using? I am unable to get your code to run without an error. Try recreating it in JSBin or something similar. Also, are you looking at the output in IE? IE has issues with styling SVGs, but can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where to begin honestly. The code snippet that you have provided on is own has many issues that prevent it from doing anything on my side.

I hope [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYmYaY) gives you a basic idea about how to scale the svg to the parent containers dimensions:

html

```
<div id="test">
    <svg></svg>
</div>
```

css

```
#test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

svg { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

js

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.attr('viewBox', '-0 -5 10 10');
svg.append('svg:path')
  .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
  .attr('fill', '#999')
  .style('stroke','none');
```

The size of the svg element itself can be set with CSS using absolute or relative units.

The viewBox attribute defines the boundaries of the SVGs internal coordinate system. To have the contents of the vector image at "full size" it should not be bigger than necessary to contain all elements of the SVG.